# wxWidgets EVT_BUTTON function parameter depending on where event came from?

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets and the EVT_BUTTON makro to manage which buttons call which functions.

What I now want to do is having two different buttons calling the same function with different parameters so that slightly different actions can be executed without duplicating a lot of code.

Of coure another possibility is not call a function with a parameter but to somehow make the separation once the function entered, but I couldn't find any useful information in the event object.

Currently it looks like this:

I have one `wxButton` with the ID 1.

and I have the function

```
void Test::Function(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    DoStuff;
}
```

I also have the wxWidgets-makro `EVT_BUTTON(1,Test::Function)` which calls the function I have when I press the button wie the ID 1.

What I want is that I'll have two buttons with the IDs 1 and 2 which will both lead to the same function and that I can distinguish them when inside the function, something like

```
void Test::Function(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    if (event.comesFromtButton1) { //how to realize this is basically my question
        doButton1Stuff;
    } else {
        doButton2Stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: some current {pseudo}code would be useful.

Comment: Use event.GetId() to obtain the identifier of the control that sent the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect `Test::Function` with both `ID 1` and `ID 2`. Inside the event handler compare `event.GetId()` to `ID 1` and `ID 2`.

Comment: Damn, that straight forward. That you!